# Show that the image of a disc under an isometry is a disc

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Page 158 of "*Basic Mathematics*" by S. Lang, Exercise 1b

> Let $F$ be an isometry which has an inverse $F^{-1}$. 
>   Let $D$ be a disc of radius $r$ and center at $P$.
>
> Show that the image of $D$ under $F$ is a disc.

We wish to show that the image of $D$ under $F$ is a disc, i.e., $F_{(D)}$ is contained in $D'$, and $D'$ is contained in $F_{(D)}$, where $D'$ is a disc of radius $r$ and center $P' = F_{(P)}$.

**Proof** $F_{(D)} \subset D'$: Let $Q$ be a point of $D$ such that
$$d(P, Q) \le r$$
For sake of argument, we let
\begin{align}
d(P, Q) = s &&\text{with $0 \le s \le r$}
\end{align}
With assumption on $F$, we have
\begin{align}
d(P, Q) & = d(F_{(P)}, F_{(Q)}) &&\text{isometries preserve distances}\\
& = d(P', F_{(Q)}) &&\text{$P' = F_{(P)}$}\\
& = s
\end{align}

Then $F_{(Q)}$ is within the disc of center at $P'$, radius $r$, which we previously defined as $D'$.

Thus the image of $D$ under $F$ must be contained in $D'$.
$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

**Proof** $D' \subset F_{(D)}$: Let $Q'$ be a point of this disc $D'$ which we previously defined, such that
\begin{align}
d(P', Q') = s &&\text{with $0 \le s \le r$}
\end{align}

Similar resoning shows that
\begin{align}
s & = d(F^{-1}_{(P')}, F^{-1}_{(Q')}) \\
& = d(P, F^{-1}_{(Q)})
\end{align}

Hence $F^{-1}_{(Q')}$ lies on the disc $D$, and thus
$$F(F^{-1}_{(Q')}) = Q'$$
is in $F_{(D)}$.
$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you have any particular concerns about this proof?

Comment: I would like to know if there is any mistake in this proof. Sorry for not making it explicit.